# Generating static map image from google with url length greater than 8000 characters

Tags: python, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to generate an image which has more than 10,000 points in route. Using the polyline encoding technique i am able to reduce the length, but thats not enough.
How can i generate an image with more than 10,000 points in google static map api.

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible. You can [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188843&template=787424).

However, I'd recommend reconsidering the need to use 10,000 points in a line that should hardly have many more than 10,000 pixels on a Static Map.